# Active x control (Does it need vb 6 runtime on client machine to work)

Tags: vb6, activex

I have developed an active x control in visual basic 6.  Does the client machines need to have visual basic runtime to be able to use this active x control in browser.

I appreciate your response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, activeX controls created in VB 6 require the runtime to installed on client machines

Comment: Thanks. What if the client has .net framework , will it work ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The VB6 runtime is required.

Comment: This answer would be better with a reference.  I'm not saying it's right or wrong, but a definitive reference would be better.